# Working with WPF and Entity Framework together - what architecture?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have been writing an application using WPF MVVM and Entity Framework for a few months now, and I am realizing that my code architecture is starting to get messy. I cannot seem to figure out a way to connect EF and WPF properly together while keeping the two layers distinct and coherent data.

The entities are always detached, since keeping them attached would mean that we would have to keep a single instance of DbContext for the whole application, which is not recommended.

Currently, this is my architecture:

- Most of write operations are put into services that never takes
  entities as argument, only their IDs.
- ViewModels call the services, but since the entities are not attached, the view is not updated
- ViewModels retrieve their data directly from a DbContext, chosing which property to include depending on what needs to be displayed

The problems:

- It doesn't feel right. I feel like I'm not using EF properly and it hirks me.
- I end up with a lot of entity instances that have undefined properties (I can't always include all of them, it would consume too much memory)
- I have EF code in my ViewModels

I also can't seem to find any proper examples of WPF - EF architecture online, other than very basic tutorials.

Example:

```
class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private Service _service;

    public ViewModel(Service service)
    {
        LoadEntities();
    }

    public IList<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    private void LoadEntities()
    {
        using(var context = new DbContext())
        {
            Entities = context.Entities
                .Include("Reference.Foo")
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    private void DeleteEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        _service.DeleteEntity(entity.Id);
        Entities.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: so you have accumulated months worth of issues. congratulations, but questions about finding tutorials are off topic on StackOverflow. get acquainted with the [tour]

Comment: There are a *lot* of relevant examples and tutorials. Everything that shows the use of an ORM in an MVVM architecture in fact. From the question it looks like you didn't understand what MVVM is or how it works: `since the entities are not attached, the view is not updated` why are you *not* binding the ViewModels to the views? That's their job, not to call services. `ViewModels retrieve their data directly from a DbContext`: No, viewmodels are created from the loaded data (Model) and bound to the views thus forcing an automatic update

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Sorry, I am not good at explaining things in english. I added a code example. The VM is bound the the view

Comment: @Romain most courses and tutorials *do* show how to load data from a database. Your code doesn't show the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged though so binding won't work.

Comment: @Romain I'd suggest you check the [Building an Enterprise App with WPF, MVVM, and Entity Framework Code First](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/wpf-mvvm-entity-framework-app/table-of-contents) course at Pluralsight. You can get 3 months free access through the Visual Studio Dev Essentials program

Comment: It's only an example, I have no problems with the MVVM side/bindings. I just find that my code isn't very coherent and I was looking for a way to fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is a very "large" question...and quite difficult to anwser on a simple post

Why focusing on EF ? architecture is the same for all....simply said : Entities; DataAccessLayer; Business Services; GUI (Views, Viewmodel, Services - are using entities and services only)

you said "Currently, this is my architecture" ==> for me the 3 points are wrongs. gives entities to services is not a problem, attach entity to viewmodel and don't call DB/EF directly in your viewmodel instead use the service

1. Assembly.Entities
2. Assembly.BusinessServices
3. Assembly.DAL
4. Assembly.GUI

Good luck

Comment: If I use the service for everything, how do I avoid bloating it with very specific methods that I need? Like, for a given view I will only need certain properties that I wouldn't need in others

Comment: @Romain Your Services are _not_ supposed to be general. They are supposed to be specific. They contain your business logic, which may be complicated.

Comment: *that is a very "large" question* Then please vote to close as "too broad". Answering off-topic questions encourages people to keep asking them.

Comment: then you use a specific Viewmodel and getter;  Your service will have GetAllCars returning CompleteCarViewModel and another GetAllCarsSimple returning SimpleCarViewModel....sure it seems "duplicated" but data access is the same, just the transformation is different - and you attach the same model CarEntity to your viewmodel

Comment: Looks like this is very I was stuck, I will make my services less generic, thanks! and my god some people are agressive here...

Comment: take a look at this as sample https://github.com/TheCamel/CBR and don't care of others....:-)

Comment: @GCamel This is awesome, exactly what I needed! thanks a lot, I'm going to study that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

- Use an IoC container for managing all/most of your dependencies, incuding DbContext. That way you can always test everything better. You can then configure the scope of these dependencies (singleton, transient, etc..). Some popular options are autofac, castle windsor, ninject or the built in ioc container from .net.
- Look into the repository pattern, it will greatly decouple everything
- Keep your ViewModels as dumb as possible
- Map the data coming from your EF Model to DTO's, don't use the entities directly in your views
- Look into the SOLID principles